# Return statement in Java

Tags: java

Here is my solution.
My code:

```
boolean pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll(int beeper) {
    int counter=0;
        while(beeper>counter) {
            pickUpItemWithRobot();
            counter++;
        } 
        return false;
}
```

There should be something wrong here, but i can't find a mistake..

Comment: "There should be something wrong here, but i can't find a mistake.." What's wrong? What's the expected result?

Comment: if it helps, counter will never = 0, so this function will never return true.

Comment: for starters counter == 0 will never evaluate to true

Comment: There's a missing `}`.

Comment: Your function basically calls pickUpItemWithRobot() until all beepers are gone. Therefore, your function should always return true. Therefore you should make it a void return type. Then: for (c=0;c<=beeper;c++) pickUpItemWithRobot();

Comment: Wait, is the beeper argument actually different from the number of beepers on the ground? If so, you cannot tell true from false without access to that number.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the wrong order of actions taken

```
int counter=0; //set conter to 0
    while(beeper>counter) {
        pickUpItemWithRobot();
        counter++;  //increment counter e.g. it will be 1 in the first loop
        if(counter==0) return true;  //never true...
```

Ok, the `counter++` is a post operator, **but** that means being done after the expression was evaluated - **not** after the loop has completed. So the next expression will see the new value: e.g. 1 for the first iteration...

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll(int beeper) {
int counter=0;
    while(beeper>counter) {
        pickUpItemWithRobot();
        counter++;

    } 
    return true;
}
```

is this some thing your looking for ??

Comment: no. there still a mistake..

Comment: From what we know, this should be the correct version. Maybe use a for loop instead of while. It also makes clear that pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll has no way of ever returning false.

Comment: what kind of ?? i think you need to return something like boolean from the method "pickUpItemWithRobot()". if pickUpItem is happening successfully then you can do next count.

Comment: This will never return false, which the OP requires in case there are no more beepers left.

Comment: Yes Alex, your rite "for" loop is better for this kind of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have will always return false as counter is never going to be 0 where it is checked. You say you want the method to return false if there are no more items to be picked up but you are never checking for that condition. You also say that there are enough beepers to make sure that pickUpItemWithRobot() never fails. You must have the total number of beepers somewhere (I will assume for now that pickUpItemWithRobot() returns the number of beepers left. You want something like this:

```
boolean pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll(int beeper) {
    int beepersLeft;
    for (i = 0; i < beeper; i++ {            
        beepresLeft = pickUpItemWithRobot();
    }
    return beepersLeft > 0;
}
```

If pickUpItemWithRobot() can not return the number of beepers left then the return statement should be somehting like:

```
return getNumberOfBeeprsLeft() > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll(int beeper) {
    for (i = 0; i = beeper; i++ {            
        try {
            pickUpItemWithRobot();
        } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

In your version counter is never 0 as you increment it each loop.

Obviously you pickUpItemWithRobot() method will need to throw the exception if it runs out of beepers.

Comment: The OP states that there are enough Beepers to do the loop safely so the ItemNotFoundException is never going to be thrown.